# magnetic effect to attach window dialog or frame to another

Tags: java, swing, location, frame

I have to windows (JFrame and non-modal JDialog) and I want to attach the JDialog to the JFrame, so that when I move the JFrame the JDialog is also moved.
The synchronous movement itself is NOT the problem. I realized it via ComponentListener.componentMoved(.).

But the attachment should not be fixed. The user should have the possibility to detach the JDialog by moving it away from JFrame. Only when JDialog is placed directly to the JFrame border it should be attached.

To help the user place the JDialog exactly next to the JFrame (attach it) I want to **implement a "magnetic effect"**: If the JDialog is moved nearer than 10px to the JFrames border the JDialog should automatically be places exactly next to the JFrame.
Detecting this situation in ComponentListener.componentMoved(.) is also not the problem, but setting the new JDialog location:

When I set the new location by JDialog.setLocation(.) first the JDialog is placed correctly. **But when I finish the dialog dragging (release the mouse button) the JDialog is placed back at the prior location (10px away from JFrame)**.

I think this is because at the end of the drag, "the system" also calls setLocation(.).
Any ideas how I can prevent this behavior? E.g. remove any following mouse movement or mouse released events from event queue?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about empty JFrame and non-modal JDialog

Comment: Have you examined any [docking frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+docking).

Comment: The docking frameworks mostly only handle InternalFrames, but not normal Frames and Dialogs.

Comment: However, meanwhile I found a solution. I will post it as answer. But because of stackoverflow restrictions I can post an answer not before 8 hours elapsed after my question post!

Comment: +1 to mKrobel for SSCCE and trashgod for Docking frameworks

Answer (score 7):

I was interested i this question and decided to make my own little program that will create an main frame/dock and other dockable containers. These containers will follow the main frame in order to remain in their positions.

So although answered I'd like to share my example.

As for why the OPs code was not working perfectly I think it was due to the fact `componentMoved` would refire on each move thus something went wrong during the movings of dockables.

Here is a small example right now you can add dockables to North, East, South and/or West of main frame. The way the dockables keep in their location is managed by layouts like - *Sticky*, *Magnetic* and *Follow Layout*.

*Sticky Layout* moves with main frame, whereas Follow *calls* dockables to *move* into main frames position and *Magnetic* does as the name assumes attracts all dockables within a certain distance it should be noted though each dockable i.e east is only attracted to the main dock if its within the given distance from its specified final/docked point (eastly top of main frame) on the main frame.

It uses a `ComponentAdapter/Listener` and `Swing Timer` with `Component#setLocation(int x,int y)` to achieve the outcome.

The below screen shot is of 4 dockables (north, west, east and south) the center screen is the main frame. The `Docker` class has a `getDockToolbar` which allows us the ability to add a toolbar which has prebuilt *dock* and *un-dock* buttons.

[image]

Here is the code (the below shows Magnetic layout):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MagneticFrameAndDialog {

    public MagneticFrameAndDialog() {
        createAndShowGUI();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MagneticFrameAndDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame (The Docks)");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Docker docker = new Docker();
        docker.registerDock(frame);
        docker.setLayout(Docker.MAGNETIC_LAYOUT);
        //docker.setMagneticFieldSize(250);//default is 150
        docker.setComponentMovedReactTime(50);//default is 100

        JDialog d1 = createAndShowDialog(300, 300);
        d1.setTitle("East Dockable");
        JDialog d2 = createAndShowDialog(300, 100);
        d2.setTitle("South Dockable");
        JDialog d3 = createAndShowDialog(100, 300);
        d3.setTitle("West Dockable");
        JDialog d4 = createAndShowDialog(300, 100);
        d4.setTitle("North Dockable");

        docker.registerDockee(d1, Docker.EAST_DOCKED);
        docker.registerDockee(d2, Docker.SOUTH_DOCKED);
        docker.registerDockee(d3, Docker.WEST_DOCKED);
        docker.registerDockee(d4, Docker.NORTH_DOCKED);

        frame.add(docker.getDockToolbar(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JDialog createAndShowDialog(final int w, final int h) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(w, h);
            }
        };
        dialog.setTitle("Dockable Dialog");
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        return dialog;
    }
}

class Docker {

    public static final String NORTH_DOCKED = "dock north", SOUTH_DOCKED = "dock south", WEST_DOCKED = " dock west", EAST_DOCKED = "dock east";
    public static final String FOLLOW_LAYOUT = "layout follow", STICKY_LAYOUT = "layout sticky", MAGNETIC_LAYOUT = "layout magnetic";
    private HashMap<Component, String> dockees = new HashMap<>();
    private Timer dockeeMoveTimer;
    private ComponentAdapter caDock, caDockee;
    private Component dock;
    private String layout = STICKY_LAYOUT;
    private int MAGNETIC_FIELD_SIZE = 150, movedReactTime = 100;

    public Docker() {
        initTimers();
        initComponentAdapters();
    }

    public void setLayout(String layout) {
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    void setComponentMovedReactTime(int milis) {
        movedReactTime = milis;
    }

    private void initComponentAdapters() {
        caDockee = new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent ce) {
                super.componentMoved(ce);
                if (layout.equals(MAGNETIC_LAYOUT)) {
                    createDockeeMovedTimer();
                } else {
                    iterateDockables();
                }
            }

            private void createDockeeMovedTimer() {
                if (dockeeMoveTimer.isRunning()) {
                    dockeeMoveTimer.restart();
                } else {
                    dockeeMoveTimer.start();
                }
            }
        };
        caDock = new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent ce) {
                super.componentMoved(ce);
                iterateDockables();
            }

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
                super.componentResized(ce);
                iterateDockables();
            }
        };
    }

    private void initTimers() {
        dockeeMoveTimer = new Timer(movedReactTime, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                iterateDockables();
            }
        });
        dockeeMoveTimer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    private void iterateDockables() {
        //System.out.println("Dock will call for Dockees to come");
        for (Map.Entry<Component, String> entry : dockees.entrySet()) {
            Component component = entry.getKey();
            String pos = entry.getValue();
            if (!isDocked(component, pos)) {
                dock(component, pos);
            }
        }
    }

    void registerDock(Component dock) {
        this.dock = dock;
        dock.addComponentListener(caDock);
    }

    void registerDockee(Component dockee, String pos) {
        dockee.addComponentListener(caDockee);
        dockees.put(dockee, pos);
        caDock.componentResized(new ComponentEvent(dock, 1));//not sure about the int but w dont use it so its fine for now
    }

    void deregisterDockee(Component dockee) {
        dockee.removeComponentListener(caDockee);
        dockees.remove(dockee);
    }

    void setMagneticFieldSize(int sizeInPixels) {
        MAGNETIC_FIELD_SIZE = sizeInPixels;
    }

    private boolean isDocked(Component comp, String pos) {
        switch (pos) {
            case EAST_DOCKED:
                int eastDockedX = dock.getX() + dock.getWidth();
                int eastDockedY = dock.getY();
                if (layout.equals(MAGNETIC_LAYOUT)) {
                    if (comp.getLocation().distance(new Point(eastDockedX, eastDockedY)) <= MAGNETIC_FIELD_SIZE) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (comp.getX() == eastDockedX && comp.getY() == eastDockedY) {
                        // System.out.println("is eastly docked");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case SOUTH_DOCKED:
                int southDockedX = dock.getX();
                int southDockedY = dock.getY() + dock.getHeight();
                if (layout.equals(MAGNETIC_LAYOUT)) {
                    if (comp.getLocation().distance(new Point(southDockedX, southDockedY)) <= MAGNETIC_FIELD_SIZE) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (comp.getX() == southDockedX && comp.getY() == southDockedY) {
                        // System.out.println("is southly docked");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case WEST_DOCKED:
                int westDockedX = dock.getX() - comp.getWidth();
                int westDockedY = dock.getY();
                if (layout.equals(MAGNETIC_LAYOUT)) {
                    if (comp.getLocation().distance(new Point(westDockedX + comp.getWidth(), westDockedY)) <= MAGNETIC_FIELD_SIZE) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (comp.getX() == westDockedX && comp.getY() == westDockedY) {
                        // System.out.println("is southly docked");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NORTH_DOCKED:
                int northDockedX = dock.getX() + comp.getHeight();
                int northDockedY = dock.getY() - comp.getHeight();
                if (layout.equals(MAGNETIC_LAYOUT)) {
                    if (comp.getLocation().distance(new Point(northDockedX - comp.getHeight(), northDockedY + comp.getHeight())) <= MAGNETIC_FIELD_SIZE) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (comp.getX() == northDockedX && comp.getY() == northDockedY) {
                        // System.out.println("is southly docked");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private Timer eastTimer = null, southTimer = null, westTimer = null, northTimer = null;

    private void dock(final Component comp, String pos) {
        //System.out.println("Snapping Dockee back to the dock");
        switch (pos) {
            case EAST_DOCKED:
                int eastDockedX = dock.getX() + dock.getWidth();
                int eastDockedY = dock.getY();
                if (eastTimer == null) {
                    eastTimer = getTimer(comp, eastDockedX, eastDockedY);
                    eastTimer.start();
                } else {
                    if (!eastTimer.isRunning()) {
                        eastTimer = getTimer(comp, eastDockedX, eastDockedY);
                        eastTimer.start();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case SOUTH_DOCKED:
                int southDockedX = dock.getX();
                int southDockedY = dock.getY() + dock.getHeight();
                if (southTimer == null) {
                    southTimer = getTimer(comp, southDockedX, southDockedY);
                    southTimer.start();
                } else {
                    if (!southTimer.isRunning()) {
                        southTimer = getTimer(comp, southDockedX, southDockedY);
                        southTimer.start();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case WEST_DOCKED:
                int westDockedX = dock.getX() - comp.getWidth();
                int westDockedY = dock.getY();
                if (westTimer == null) {
                    westTimer = getTimer(comp, westDockedX, westDockedY);
                    westTimer.start();
                } else {
                    if (!westTimer.isRunning()) {
                        westTimer = getTimer(comp, westDockedX, westDockedY);
                        westTimer.start();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NORTH_DOCKED:
                int northDockedX = dock.getX();
                int northDockedY = dock.getY() - comp.getHeight();
                if (northTimer == null) {
                    northTimer = getTimer(comp, northDockedX, northDockedY);
                    northTimer.start();
                } else {
                    if (!northTimer.isRunning()) {
                        northTimer = getTimer(comp, northDockedX, northDockedY);
                        northTimer.start();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private Timer getTimer(final Component comp, int finalX, int finalY) {
        Timer t = null;
        switch (layout) {
            case STICKY_LAYOUT:
                t = stickyDockableTimer(comp, finalX, finalY);
                break;
            case FOLLOW_LAYOUT:
                t = followDockableTimer(comp, finalX, finalY);
                break;
            case MAGNETIC_LAYOUT:
                t = followDockableTimer(comp, finalX, finalY);
                break;
        }
        return t;
    }

    private Timer followDockableTimer(final Component comp, final int finalX, final int finalY) {
        Timer t = new Timer(1, new AbstractAction() {
            int INCREMENT = 1, DECREMENT = 1;
            int x = comp.getX(), y = comp.getY();

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //System.out.println(finalX + "," + finalY);
                if (x < finalX) {
                    x += INCREMENT;
                } else if (x > finalX) {
                    x -= DECREMENT;
                }
                if (y < finalY) {
                    y += INCREMENT;
                } else if (y > finalY) {
                    y -= DECREMENT;
                }
                comp.setLocation(x, y);
                if (x == finalX && y == finalY) {
                    if (comp instanceof Window) {
                        ((Window) comp).toFront();
                    }
                    ((Timer) ae.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        return t;
    }

    public JPanel getDockToolbar() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        for (Map.Entry<Component, String> entry : dockees.entrySet()) {
            final Component component = entry.getKey();
            String pos = entry.getValue();
            Docker.MyButton jtb = new Docker.MyButton("un-dock" + pos.replace("dock", ""), component, pos);
            panel.add(jtb);
            jtb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    Docker.MyButton jtb = (Docker.MyButton) ae.getSource();
                    String tmp = jtb.getText();
                    if (tmp.contains("un-dock")) {
                        jtb.setText(tmp.replace("un-dock", "dock"));
                        deregisterDockee(jtb.getComponent());
                    } else {
                        jtb.setText(tmp.replace("dock", "un-dock"));
                        registerDockee(jtb.getComponent(), jtb.getDockablePosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return panel;
    }

    private Timer stickyDockableTimer(final Component comp, final int finalX, final int finalY) {
        Timer t = new Timer(1, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                comp.setLocation(finalX, finalY);
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(false);
        return t;
    }

    private class MyButton extends JButton {

        private final Component c;
        private final String pos;

        public MyButton(String text, Component c, String pos) {
            super(text);
            this.c = c;
            this.pos = pos;
        }

        public Component getComponent() {
            return c;
        }

        public String getDockablePosition() {
            return pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mojays see my update added Magnetic Layout for the Docker class (changed example accordingly)

Answer (score 4):

I posted the upper mentioned question after hours of ineffective searching and trial and error.
And after some more minutes of searching I found the solution... D'oh!

The trick is not to set the location of the dialog directly by JDialog.setLocation(.) during ComponentListener.componentMoved(.), but simply modify the mouse position (which is still in drag mode!):

```
// Example ONLY for magnetic effect on EAST border of JFrame!!
int dockDistE = ...; // distance on east border of JFrame to west border of JDialog
...
try {
  // determine mouse location
  Point mouseLoc = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
  Robot robot = new Robot();
  // move mouse to west exactly the remaining distance to JFrame
  robot.mouseMove(mouseLoc.x-dockDistE, mouseLoc.y);
  // release mouse button to automatically finish dragging
  robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
} catch (AWTException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Modifying the mouse position results in an automatic window drag/move for the JDialog to the attach position.

Here you can find my complete DockingListener:
http://wald.intevation.org/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/schmitzm-core/src/main/java/de/schmitzm/swing/event/DockingListener.java?root=schmitzm&view=markup
There are no other dependencies than JDK (1.6).

Comment: +1 for getting your own answer. Please see an alternative [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14104818/1133011)

Answer (score 0):

I made a class called DockingManager that lets you dock Dialogs and Frames pseudo Winamp Style

It also lets you make different clusters and set magnetic levels to choose which frame drags the others)

```
package com.gsteren.docking;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class DockingManager {

    public static enum DockingMode {
        EAST, WEST, NORTH, SOUTH, NONE
    }

    int magneticDistance = 20;

    public static Map<Component, DockingApplier> monitoredComponents = new HashMap<Component, DockingApplier>();

    /**
     * Para saber cual es el último Component movido por el usuario.
     */
    private static DockingApplier focusedApplier;

    public void registerComponent(Component component) {
        this.registerComponent(component, 1);
    }

    public void registerComponent(Component component, int magneticLevel) {
        DockingApplier applier = new DockingApplier(component, magneticLevel);
        monitoredComponents.put(component, applier);
    }

    /**
     * Indica el grupo completo de componentes pegados al que pertenece un
     * componente.
     * 
     * @author Guillermo
     * 
     */
    protected class DockingApplierCluster {
        Set<DockingApplier> appliers = new HashSet<DockingApplier>();
        DockingApplier leader = null;

        public DockingApplierCluster(DockingApplier applier) {
            this.addToCluster(applier);
        }

        public DockingApplierCluster(Set<DockingApplier> appliers) {
            for (DockingApplier applier : appliers) {
                this.addToCluster(applier);
            }
        }

        public void addToCluster(DockingApplier applier) {
            appliers.add(applier);
            applier.setCluster(this);
            if (null == leader || applier.getMagneticLevel() < leader.getMagneticLevel()) {
                this.setLeader(applier);
            }
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return getAppliers().size();
        }

        public void mergeCluster(DockingApplierCluster cluster) {
            DockingApplierCluster bigCluster;
            DockingApplierCluster smallCluster;
            if (getSize() > cluster.getSize()) {
                bigCluster = this;
                smallCluster = cluster;
            } else {
                bigCluster = cluster;
                smallCluster = this;
            }
            for (DockingApplier applier : smallCluster.getAppliers()) {
                bigCluster.addToCluster(applier);
            }

        }

        public Set<DockingApplier> getAppliers() {
            return this.appliers;
        }

        /**
         * @return the leader
         */
        public DockingApplier getLeader() {
            return leader;
        }

        /**
         * @param leader
         *            the leader to set
         */
        public void setLeader(DockingApplier leader) {
            this.leader = leader;
        }

        public void remove(DockingApplier applier) {
            if (this.getAppliers().size() == 1) {
                /* No sacamos el único elemento */
                return;
            }

            this.getAppliers().remove(applier);

            if (this.leader == applier) {
                this.leader = findLeader();
            }

            /* Pude haber dividido en varios clusters */
            this.recalculateClustersAfterRemoval();
        }

        public void recalculateClustersAfterRemoval() {
            Set<DockingApplier> myAppliersCopy = new HashSet<DockingManager.DockingApplier>(getAppliers());
            Set<DockingApplier> visitedAppliers = new HashSet<DockingManager.DockingApplier>();
            for (DockingApplier applier : myAppliersCopy) {
                if (visitedAppliers.contains(applier)) {
                    continue;
                }
                Set<DockingApplier> newClusterComponents = findClusteredAppliers(applier);
                if (newClusterComponents.size() == myAppliersCopy.size()) {
                    /* No se dividieron los clusters */
                    return;
                }
                visitedAppliers.addAll(newClusterComponents);
                /* Creo un nuevo cluster, y le agrego los elementos */
                new DockingApplierCluster(newClusterComponents);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Devuelve todos los DockingAppliers anexos entre si.
         * 
         * @param anApplier
         * @return
         */
        public Set<DockingApplier> findClusteredAppliers(DockingApplier anApplier) {
            return findClusteredAppliers(anApplier, new HashSet<DockingManager.DockingApplier>());
        }

        public Set<DockingApplier> findClusteredAppliers(DockingApplier anApplier, Set<DockingApplier> currentSet) {
            currentSet.add(anApplier);
            for (DockingApplier applier : anApplier.getAttachedComponents()) {
                if (currentSet.contains(applier)) {
                    continue;
                }
                currentSet.add(applier);
                currentSet.addAll(findClusteredAppliers(applier, currentSet));
            }
            return currentSet;
        }

        private DockingApplier findLeader() {
            DockingApplier leaderCandidate = null;
            for (DockingApplier applier : getAppliers()) {
                if (leaderCandidate == null || applier.getMagneticLevel() < leaderCandidate.getMagneticLevel()) {
                    leaderCandidate = applier;
                    if (applier.getMagneticLevel() == 1) {
                        /* Encontramos óptimo */
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return leaderCandidate;
        }

    }

    protected class DockingApplier implements ComponentListener, FocusListener {

        private Component component = null;
        private DockingApplierCluster cluster;

        public DockingApplier(Component component, int magneticLevel) {
            this.component = component;
            this.cluster = new DockingApplierCluster(this);
            this.magneticLevel = magneticLevel;
            this.updateLastLocation();

            /*
             * Esto no es necesario ya que registerComponent es quien crea el
             * applier
             */
            if (!monitoredComponents.containsKey(component)) {
                monitoredComponents.put(component, this);
            }

            this.component.addComponentListener(this);
            this.component.addFocusListener(this);
            componentFinishedMovingDetector.setRepeats(false);
        }

        public void setCluster(DockingApplierCluster cluster) {
            this.cluster = cluster;
        }

        /**
         * @return the cluster
         */
        public DockingApplierCluster getCluster() {
            return cluster;
        }

        boolean isClusterLeader() {
            return getCluster().getLeader() == this;
        }

        /**
         * @return the magneticLevel
         */
        public Integer getMagneticLevel() {
            return magneticLevel;
        }

        /**
         * @param magneticLevel
         *            the magneticLevel to set
         */
        public void setMagneticLevel(Integer magneticLevel) {
            this.magneticLevel = magneticLevel;
        }

        /**
         * @return the isDocking
         */
        protected boolean isDocking() {
            return isDocking;
        }

        /**
         * @param isDocking
         *            the isDocking to set
         */
        protected void setDocking(boolean isDocking) {
            this.isDocking = isDocking;
        }

        /**
         * @return the attachedComponents
         */
        public Set<DockingApplier> getAttachedComponents() {
            return attachedComponents;
        }

        int northY;
        int southY;
        int westX;
        int eastX;

        public void recalculateBorderCoordinates() {
            Point compLoc = component.getLocation();
            Dimension compDim = component.getSize();
            northY = compLoc.y;
            southY = northY + compDim.height;
            westX = compLoc.x;
            eastX = westX + compDim.width;
        }

        public DockingMode calculateWhereToDock(DockingApplier other, int magneticDistance) {
            return calculateWhereToDock(this, other, magneticDistance);
        }

        /**
         * Indica si me debería lockearse con other
         * 
         * @param me
         * @param other
         * @return
         */
        public DockingMode calculateWhereToDock(DockingApplier me, DockingApplier other, int magneticDistance) {

            /* Talvez innecesario */
            me.recalculateBorderCoordinates();
            other.recalculateBorderCoordinates();

            if (me.getAttachedComponents().contains(other)) {
                /* Ya estan conectados */
                return DockingMode.NONE;
            }

            int dockDistN = me.northY - other.southY;
            int dockDistS = other.northY - me.southY;
            int dockDistW = me.westX - other.eastX;
            int dockDistE = other.westX - me.eastX;

            if (dockDistN > 0 && magneticDistance > dockDistN && checkOverlappingEastWest(me, other)) {
                return DockingMode.NORTH;
            } else if (dockDistS > 0 && magneticDistance > dockDistS && checkOverlappingEastWest(me, other)) {
                return DockingMode.SOUTH;
            } else if (dockDistW > 0 && magneticDistance > dockDistW && checkOverlappingNorthSouth(me, other)) {
                return DockingMode.WEST;
            } else if (dockDistE > 0 && magneticDistance > dockDistE && checkOverlappingNorthSouth(me, other)) {
                return DockingMode.EAST;
            }
            return DockingMode.NONE;
        }

        /**
         * Checks whether components overlap in north/south direction.
         */
        protected boolean checkOverlappingEastWest(DockingApplier me, DockingApplier other) {
            return checkOverlappingEastWest_aux(me, other) || checkOverlappingEastWest_aux(other, me);
        }

        /**
         * Checks whether components overlap in east/west direction.
         */
        protected boolean checkOverlappingEastWest_aux(DockingApplier me, DockingApplier other) {
            return me.westX >= other.westX && me.westX <= other.eastX || me.eastX >= other.westX
                    && me.eastX <= other.eastX;
        }

        /**
         * Checks whether components overlap in north/south direction.
         */
        protected boolean checkOverlappingNorthSouth(DockingApplier me, DockingApplier other) {
            return checkOverlappingNorthSouth_aux(me, other) || checkOverlappingNorthSouth_aux(other, me);
        }

        /**
         * Checks whether components overlap in north/south direction.
         */
        protected boolean checkOverlappingNorthSouth_aux(DockingApplier me, DockingApplier other) {
            return me.northY >= other.northY && me.northY <= other.southY || me.southY >= other.northY
                    && me.southY <= other.southY;
        }

        public Point calculateDockedLocation(DockingApplier other, DockingMode mode) {
            return calculateDockedLocation(this, other, mode);
        }

        public Point calculateDockedLocation(DockingApplier me, DockingApplier other, DockingMode mode) {
            final Point meLoc = me.getComponent().getLocation();
            final Point otherLoc = other.getComponent().getLocation();
            final Dimension otherDim = other.getComponent().getSize();
            final Dimension meDim = me.getComponent().getSize();

            /* Posiciones relativas a other */
            switch (mode) {
            case NORTH:
                return new Point(meLoc.x, otherLoc.y + otherDim.height);
            case SOUTH:
                return new Point(meLoc.x, otherLoc.y - meDim.height);
            case WEST:
                return new Point(otherLoc.x + otherDim.width, meLoc.y);
            case EAST:
                return new Point(otherLoc.x - meDim.width, meLoc.y);
            default:
                return new Point(meLoc.x - otherLoc.x, meLoc.y);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Retrasa la accion a ejecutar en onComponentFinishedMoving hasta que
         * pasan 10ms sin que se mueva el componente afectado.
         */
        Timer componentFinishedMovingDetector = new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onComponentFinishedMoving();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Resetea el componentFinishedMovingDetector, se debe llamar cada vez
         * que se mueve o cambia el tamaño de la ventana.
         */
        protected void startComponentFinishedMovingDetector() {
            if (componentFinishedMovingDetector.isRunning()) {
                componentFinishedMovingDetector.restart();
            } else {
                componentFinishedMovingDetector.start();
            }
        }

        /* Mientras es menor, más probable es ser lider */
        int magneticLevel = 1;

        /* Indica si el componente esta en proceso de hacer dock */
        boolean isDocking = false;

        /* Para desconectarlos en resize */
        Set<DockingApplier> attachedComponents = new HashSet<DockingApplier>();
        /* Indica la posición del componente */
        private Point lastLocation;

        public boolean isDocked() {
            return getCluster().getSize() > 1;
        }

        /**
         * @return the component
         */
        protected Component getComponent() {
            return component;
        }

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            startComponentFinishedMovingDetector();
            this.recalculateBorderCoordinates();
            this.unDock();
        }

        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

            this.recalculateBorderCoordinates();

            /*
             * Si el movimiento es consecuencia de hacer dock lo ignoro y marco
             * como que el docking se completó
             */
            if (this.isDocking()) {
                this.setDocking(false);
                return;
            }

            startComponentFinishedMovingDetector();

            if (this != focusedApplier) {
                return;
            }

            if (getCluster().getSize() == 1) {
                return;
            }

            if (!this.isClusterLeader()) {
                this.updateLastLocation();
                this.unDock();
                return;
            }

            positionAttachedComponents();

        }

        public void onComponentFinishedMoving() {
            this.recalculateBorderCoordinates();
            for (DockingApplier otherDockingApplier : getMonitoredComponents().values()) {
                if (otherDockingApplier == this) {
                    continue;
                }
                DockingMode dockMode = calculateWhereToDock(this, otherDockingApplier);
                if (!DockingMode.NONE.equals(dockMode)) {
                    System.out.println("shouldAttach");
                    this.dock(otherDockingApplier, dockMode);                   
                    this.updateLastLocation();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("shouldNotAttach");
                }
            }
        }

        public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
            this.setLocation(new Point(x, y));
        }

        public void setLocation(Point location) {
            this.getComponent().removeComponentListener(this);
            this.getComponent().setLocation(location);
            this.setLastLocation(location);
            this.getComponent().addComponentListener(this);
        }

        private void setLastLocation(Point location) {
            this.lastLocation = location;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return this.getComponent().getLocation();
        }

        /**
         * @return the lastLocation
         */
        public Point getLastLocation() {
            return lastLocation;
        }

        protected void dock(DockingApplier otherDockingApplier, DockingMode dockMode) {
            this.setDocking(true);
            Point dockInfo = this.calculateDockedLocation(otherDockingApplier, dockMode);
            this.setLocation(dockInfo.x, dockInfo.y);
            this.bindAppliers(otherDockingApplier);
            /* Uno los clusters */
            otherDockingApplier.getCluster().mergeCluster(this.getCluster());
        }

        public void bindAppliers(DockingApplier otherDockingApplier) {
            this.getAttachedComponents().add(otherDockingApplier);
            otherDockingApplier.getAttachedComponents().add(this);
        }

        public void unDock() {
            if (this.getCluster().getSize() == 1) {
                return;
            }
            /*
             * Primero lo quito de sus vecinos, luego del cluster, el orden es
             * importante para el calculo de clusters en caso de división.
             */
            Set<DockingApplier> attachedComponentsCopy = new HashSet<DockingManager.DockingApplier>(
                    this.getAttachedComponents());
            for (DockingApplier applier : attachedComponentsCopy) {
                this.unbind(applier);
            }

            this.getCluster().remove(this);
            this.setCluster(new DockingApplierCluster(this));
        }

        public void unbind(DockingApplier dockingApplier) {
            this.getAttachedComponents().remove(dockingApplier);
            dockingApplier.getAttachedComponents().remove(this);
        }

        private DockingMode calculateWhereToDock(DockingApplier component, DockingApplier otherDockingApplier) {
            return this.calculateWhereToDock(otherDockingApplier, magneticDistance);
        }

        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            getMonitoredComponents().get(component).recalculateBorderCoordinates();
            // positionAttachedComponents(e);
        }

        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            getMonitoredComponents().get(component).recalculateBorderCoordinates();
            // positionAttachedComponents(e);
        }

        private void positionAttachedComponents() {

            /* El lider del cluster debe arrastrar a los otros componentes */
            Point currentLocation = getComponent().getLocation();
            int xDiff = currentLocation.x - getLastLocation().x;
            int yDiff = currentLocation.y - getLastLocation().y;

            if (xDiff == 0 && yDiff == 0) {
                return;
            }

            this.updateLastLocation();

            for (DockingApplier otherApplier : getCluster().getAppliers()) {
                if (otherApplier == this) {
                    continue;
                }
                Point otherComponentLocation = otherApplier.getComponent().getLocation();
                otherApplier.getComponent().removeComponentListener(otherApplier);
                otherApplier.setDocking(true);
                otherApplier.getComponent().setLocation(otherComponentLocation.x + xDiff,
                        otherComponentLocation.y + yDiff);
                otherApplier.getComponent().addComponentListener(otherApplier);
            }
        }

        public void updateLastLocation() {
            this.setLastLocation(getComponent().getLocation());
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            DockingManager.setFocusedApplier(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    public DockingManager() {

    }

    public static void setFocusedApplier(DockingApplier applier) {
        DockingManager.focusedApplier = applier;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Frame 1");
        JDialog dialog2 = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Dialog 2");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(200, 50);
        dialog2.setSize(200, 50);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        dialog2.setVisible(true);

        JDialog dialog1 = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Dialog 1");
        dialog1.setSize(200, 50);
        dialog1.setVisible(true);

        DockingManager manager = new DockingManager();

        manager.registerComponent(frame1, 1);
        manager.registerComponent(dialog2, 2);
        manager.registerComponent(dialog1, 2);

    }

    /**
     * @return the monitoredComponents
     */
    protected static Map<Component, DockingApplier> getMonitoredComponents() {
        return monitoredComponents;
    }
}
```